A psychologist/therapist follows a client and gets framed by her
Recently I saw half of a movie and cannot remember the name. I thought Clive Owen played in it but cannot find it. 
I remember parts, specifically that he was a psychologist or therapist and had a client which he followed. He suspected she killed people so he follows her. She goes down an alley and looks like she is about to be mugged when in fact she is going in to an sex/orgy house. He runs in thinking she is going to be raped and when he looks through the sky window, she is having sex in a room full of people having sex. 
Later he goes to meet his ex-wife at a bar, they engage in an argument and he later finds her with her throat slit in a bathroom stall in the women's  bathroom. 
He has a sexual relationship with his client and I also remember he tried to drown her in her hot tub but then stopped. At the end of the movie he gets framed and ends up in a mental hospital or institution and she comes back to see him and that's how the movie ends.
I also remember at the beginning of the movie he sits down with her to conduct an interview, which she was hot and he insisted it was just them two. And at the end of the convo he asks her a question about killing people and she asks him the same. he replies no, and then she says, you haven't yet... so the rest of the movie I believe she was trying to frame him.

Welcome to Movies & TV! I've edited your question title to make it more useful. If you feel I have misunderstood you, please feel free to [edit] it yourself. In future, please make sure your title is descriptive and that it accurately represents your question. Can you please explain which woman you're mentioning in the last paragraph? I'm guessing you mean the client, but it's unclear... I'd assume he had a sexual relationship with his wife but I don't think that fits.

The sexual relationship was with his client. He suspected her to be the one killing people. So he follows her. she goes down an alley and looks like she is about to be mugged when in fact she is going in to an sex/orgi house. He runs in thinking she is going to be raped and when he looks through the sky windown she is having sex in a room full of people having sex.

I also remember at the beginning of the movie he sits down with her to conduct an interview, which she was hott and he insisted it was just them two. And at the end of the convo he asks her a question about killing people and she asks him the same. he replies no, and then she says you havent yet...so the rest of the movie I believe she was trying ot frame him.

You're looking for Basic Instinct 2 with Sharon Stone and David Morrissey.

In London, while using drugs and having sex in a speeding car with a famous soccer player, the blond writer Catherine Tramell drives off the road, falls in the river and the athlete drowns. Dr. Michael Glass is assigned for a forensic evaluation, and in spite of being against bail, Catherine is released. Later Catherine goes to Dr. Michael's office and initiates therapy with him, and he sees that she is an omnipotent manipulative woman. However, as far as Dr. Michael knows her deeper and deeper, he becomes obsessed for her, while people of their relationship are killed.

All the scenes you mentioned are there (seeing an orgy through a skylight, his ex with her throat slit, the mindgames and him being framed, him trying to drown Tramell in a sauna etc.) Here's the trailer:




I don't blame you for forgetting what this was, BTW. I'm pretty sure I once sat through this thing, and yet I remembered nothing but the basic premise (and the dead ex) and had to read a synopsis to be reminded of the rest. The film is... not great. ;)
